# The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-4.0, db2

I am getting the following error trying to connect to DB2 Entity with .Net 4.0

The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString.

I get it on this line within the generated code of my entity cs file

```
  public DOCUMAKRContainer() : base("name=DOCUMAKRContainer", "DOCUMAKRContainer")  
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }
```

My App.config (which is created when you create entity the looks like this

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
    <configSections />
      <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DOCUMAKRContainer" 
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Documakr.csdl|res://*/Documakr.ssdl|res://*/Documakr.msl;provider=IBM.Data.DB2;provider connection string=&quot;Database=DCCPDEVL;User ID=documakr;Password=Dcpd@123;server.com:60000&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
```

I have tried to delete and rebuild the entity and get the same results every time. All of this is generated code when you add an entity object, so I am wondering if it is a VS 2010/IBM DB2 issue. Internet has not really given me any help.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site is a good resource: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

It looks you have have some garbage in your connection string:

```
provider connection string=&quot;Database
```

Actually, it looks like you've got a conection string jammed into your connection string.

Also, you might want to edit your post and remove or ##### the login info.

Comment: +1.  To expound on this slightly, the actual string you want is between the two &quot; instances

Comment: this is actually a valid Entity Framework connection string (the ConnectionString setting contains some meta data and the connection string itself between quotes which are encoded to `&quot;` so to not mess with the XML well-formedness of the conf file). There must be something else...